# Samsung smart tv app looks different on TV than in simulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, samsung-smart-tv

I am developing a Javascript Samsung smart tv app. When I test it in the simulator it looks fine.

However when I send it to the TV to test, it looks a lot different. Is this a common problem? Is there anything I need to change? For some reason it seems like some parts appear much larger on the TV (images and such).

More importantly though, what is the best way to do debugging on the TV?

Comment: What TV model and emulator you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Emulator does not reflect the perfect behaviour. It has some limitations and you cannot be sure about the functionality of your app without testing on a real device.

However, a better option is available now [Remote Test System](https://rts.samsungdforum.com/). You can choose specific device model for testing and debugging. It is more accurate and you can do more things on it as compared to a emulator